# How should I add separators to my tkinter app, or how should i make the items form vertical columns using the pack() function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a password manager using Tkinter and I am facing difficulty in making my password viewer as such, form vertical columns

current code

```py
class PassWordViewer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        welcome = Label(self, text='Here Are Your Stored PassWords', font=SUB_LABEL_FONT)
        welcome.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        manager = PasswordManager()
        data = manager.get_from_database() # password, username, website

        for password, username, website in data:
            blank_frame = Frame(self)

            web_label = Label(blank_frame, text= website, font= BUTTON_FONT)
            web_label.pack(side= LEFT)

            username_label = Label(blank_frame, text= username, font= BUTTON_FONT)
            username_label.pack(side= LEFT)

            password_label = Label(blank_frame, text= password, font= BUTTON_FONT)
            password_label.pack(side= LEFT)
            blank_frame.pack()

        return_button = Button(
            self, text='Back To PassWord Manager', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PassWordManagerMain),
            font=BUTTON_FONT
        )

        return_button.pack(pady= 15)
```

this is how it currently looks

[image: APPLICATION]

with the format, website then username and then the password (the passwords here are test ones and don't lead to anything)

As visible it looks untidy and i would like for it be in columns of website, username, password with equal separation space between them

[Here is the link to the full code](https://pastebin.com/YyUMUMus)

Thanks for you help :D

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you aware that you can use `grid` to arrange items in columns? Using `grid` to make columns is going to be a bit easier than using `pack`.

Comment: yes but i was told not to mix up `grid` and `pack` together, and since i used `pack` for other frames i assumed i had to use `pack` here too, am i correct in this thinking?

Comment: @DrCrossBones you cannot mix them within the same container but you can use whatever you want within each container. Example you may have used pack() to place a frame but you can use grid() inside that frame without issue.

Comment: oh i didn't know that, thanks a lot @Mike-SMT for the help! ill try it using `grid`

Answer (score 0):

added

```py
        data_frame = Frame(self)
        for row in range(len(data)):
            for column in range(len(data[0])):
                e = Entry(data_frame, width= 10, font=BUTTON_FONT)

                e.grid(row=row, column=column)
                e.insert(END, data[row][column])
    
        data_frame.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want columns, you should use `grid`. You can use both `grid` and `pack` in the same application as long as you don't use them both for widgets that share a common parent.

Here's an example that creates a frame for the table of usernames and password. The frame is added with `pack` into the window, and the labels are added with `grid` to the frame:

```
class PassWordViewer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        password_frame = Frame(self)
        password_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both")

        for row, (password, username, website) in enumerate(data):
            web_label = Label(password_frame, text= website, font= BUTTON_FONT)
            username_label = Label(password_frame, text= username, font= BUTTON_FONT)
            password_label = Label(password_frame, text= password, font= BUTTON_FONT)

            web_label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="w")
            username_label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="w")
            password_label.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="w")

        ...
```